# Coq - Rewriting a FMap Within a Relation

Tags: programming-languages, coq, proof

I am new to Coq, and was hoping that someone with more experience could help me with a problem I am facing.

I have defined a relation to represent the evaluation of a program in an imaginary programming language. The goal of the language is unify function calls and a constrained subset of macro invocations under a single semantics. Here is the definition of the relation, with its first constructor (I am omitting the rest to save space and avoid unnecessary details).

```
Inductive EvalExpr:
  store ->         (* Store, mapping L-values to R-values *)
  environment ->   (* Local environment, mapping function-local variables names to L-values *)
  environment ->   (* Global environment, mapping global variables names to L-values *) 
  function_table ->(* Mapping function names to function definitions *)
  macro_table ->   (* Mapping macro names to macro definitions *)
  expr ->          (* The expression to evaluate *)
  Z ->             (* The value the expression terminates to *)
  store ->         (* The final state of the program store after evaluation *)
  Prop :=
  (* Numerals evaluate to their integer representation and do not
     change the store *)
  | E_Num : forall S E G F M z,
    EvalExpr S E G F M (Num z) z S
    ...
```

The mappings are defined as follows:

```
Module Import NatMap := FMapList.Make(OrderedTypeEx.Nat_as_OT).
Module Import StringMap := FMapList.Make(OrderedTypeEx.String_as_OT).

Definition store : Type := NatMap.t Z.
Definition environment : Type := StringMap.t nat.
Definition function_table : Type := StringMap.t function_definition.
Definition macro_table : Type := StringMap.t macro_definition.
```

I do not think the definitions of the other types are relevant to this question, but I can add them if needed.

Now when trying to prove the following lemma, which seems intuitively obvious, I get stuck:

```
Lemma S_Equal_EvalExpr_EvalExpr : forall S1 S2,
  NatMap.Equal S1 S2 ->
  forall E G F M e v S',
  EvalExpr S1 E G F M e v S' <-> EvalExpr S2 E G F M e v S'.
Proof.
  intros. split.
  (* -> *)
  - intros. induction H0.
    + (* Num *)
      Fail constructor.
      Abort.
```

If I were able to rewrite S2 for S1 in the goal, the proof would be trivial; however, if I try to do this, I get the following error:

```
H : NatMap.Equal S S2
(* Other premises *)
---------------------
EvalExpr S2 E G F M (Num z) z S


rewrite <- H.
```

```
Found no subterm matching "NatMap.find (elt:=Z) ?M2433 S2" in the current goal.
```

I think this has to do with finite mappings being abstract types, and thus not being rewritable like concrete types are. However, I noticed that I *can* rewrite mappings within other equations/relations found in Coq.FSets.FMapFacts. How would I tell Coq to let me rewrite mapping types inside my `EvalExpr` relation?

Update: [Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/PappasBrent/140de54b8dbf9bf25214852c6e99daf5) containing a minimal working example of my problem. The definitions of some of the mapping types have been altered for brevity, but the problem is the same.

Comment: Hi, could you create a minimal working example that has same problem that you are asking about?  It makes it easier for someone to answer if they can just paste a few lines into their editor, and more useful for others that face a similar problem in another context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arthur's answer explains the problem very well.

One other (?) way to do it could be to modify your Inductive definition of `EvalExpr` to explicitly use the equality that you care about (`NatMap.Equal` instead of `Eq`). You will have to say in each rule that it is enough for two maps to be Equal.

For example:

```
  | E_Num : forall S E G F M z, 
      EvalExpr S E G F M (Num z) z S
```

becomes

```
  | E_Num : forall S1 S2 E G F M z, 
      NatMap.Equal S1 S2 ->
      EvalExpr S1 E G F M (Num z) z S2
```

Then when you want to prove your Lemma and apply the constructor, you will have to provide a proof that S1 and S2 are equal. (you'll have to reason a little using that NatMap.Equal is an equivalence relation).

Comment: This solution is so straightforward, I wish I would have thought of it earlier. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that the relation `NatMap.Equal`, which says that two maps have the same bindings, is *not* the same as the notion of equality in Coq's logic, `=`. While it is always possible to rewrite with `=`, rewriting with some other relation `R` is only possible if you can prove that the property you are trying to show is compatible with it. This is already done for the relations in `FMap`, which is why rewriting there works.

You have two options:

1. Replace `FMap` with an implementation for which the intended map equality coincides with `=`, a property usually known as *extensionality*. There are many libraries that provide such data structures, including my own [extructures](https://github.com/arthuraa/extructures), but also [finmap](https://github.com/math-comp/finmap) and [std++](https://gitlab.mpi-sws.org/iris/stdpp). Then, you never need to worry about a custom equality relation; all the important properties of maps work with `=`.
2. Keep `FMap`, but use the [generalized rewriting](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/generalized-rewriting.html) mechanism to allow rewriting with `FMap.Equal`. To do this, you probably need to modify the definition of your execution relation so that it is compatible with `FMap.Equal`. Unfortunately, I believe the only way to do this is by explicitly adding equality hypotheses everywhere, e.g.

   ```
   Definition EvalExpr' S E G F M e v S' :=
     exists S0 S0', NatMap.Equal S S0 /\
                    NatMap.Equal S' S0' /\
                    EvalExpr S0 E G F M e v S0'.
   ```

   Since this will pollute your definitions, I would not recommend this approach.

Comment: Thank you for providing me with a variety of options, the first one sounds more appealing to me. I have not tried installing libraries for Coq yet, but your extructures library seems simple to set up and use, so I may give it a try. Thank you!